# How can I reach a single local machine through OpenVPN?

Tags: routing, openvpn

This looks like a trivial question, but I couldn't find the answer yet.

In my LAN (blue in the picture) I have a NAS and a Raspberry Pi, among other machines. I installed an OpenVPN server in the Raspberry Pi. 
I want the OpenVPN client to be able to access the NAS, meaning FTP, HTTP, etc.
The client must not be able to access any machine other than the Raspberry and the NAS itself.

In this picture you have my networks topology:

[image: networks_topology]

I can connect OpenVPN client to its server.
I know I have a subnet conflict but I cannot change the subnets.

My server configuration:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/myserver.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/myserver.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
#push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"

ifconfig-pool-persist /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/ipp.txt

keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun

status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
#log         /var/log/openvpn.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
```

My client configuration file:

```
client

remote x.y.z.t 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca /etc/openvpnclient/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpnclient/client.crt
key /etc/openvpnclient/client.key

cipher AES-128-CBC

#route-method exe
#route-delay 3
#route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
###route-nopull
route 192.168.1.20 255.255.255.255

resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun

mute 20
verb 3
```

I can connect using the Windows client, but I cannot ping or access anyway the NAS. I am sure I am still missing something, but couldn't figure out how I can route the traffic. I have read many topics on the subject, but still no luck.

I should be able to add a routing rule in the router that is over the OpenVPN server network, if needed.

### Update 18/11/2019 @17.31 CET


I have two main requirements:

1. I need the client to reach the NAS, but not the other machines on the LAN;
2. I need the client to be able to connect even when its subnet conflicts with the NAS subnet (i.e. 192.168.1.0/24).

Tom Yan and [this article](https://blog.remibergsma.com/2013/01/13/howto-connect-to-hosts-on-a-remote-network-using-openvpn-and-some-routing/) helped me getting a solution to first issue. I believe second issue is still uncovered.

**Solution for issue #1:**

In server configuration I needed to add (uncomment) this line, to ensure routing requests from the OpenVPN client to the NAS:

```
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
```

To enable routing from the NAS back to the OpenVPN client I added this routing rule **in the NAS**:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0
```

adding this line in that (empty) configuration file

```
10.8.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.88
```

And a `service network restart` ensured the static route to be applied.

After that, I restricted traffic **in the Raspberry Pi** through iptables. I actually made it permanent installing `iptables-persistent` and following [this guide](http://smartathome.blogspot.com/2018/02/an-example-iptables-rules-file-for-your.html).

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.20 -j ACCEPT
```

### Update #2

Yes, I need many clients to be able to connect and I guess I should avoid NAT and masquerading for this reason.

Comment: Please downvoter help me improve my answer: what's wrong or missing?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a route for `10.8.0.0/24` (where the gateway would be `192.168.1.88`, i.e. `Rasp.Pi` the OVPN server) to either `NAS` or `ROUTER` (assuming `ROUTER` is the default gateway of `NAS` in that case, of course), so that `NAS`/`ROUTER` would know where to direct the reply traffics.

If you cannot, you will need to do `SNAT`/`MASQUERADE` with `iptables` (or `nftables`, of course) on `Rasp.Pi` so that all traffics from the VPN clients would appear to be originated from the server.

> The client must not be able to access any machine other than the Raspberry and the NAS itself.

Make sure you limit forwarding traffics with `iptables`. Once you have enabled IP forwarding on `Rasp.Pi` (you have to, otherwise the VPN clients won't be able to reach its LAN), a client can add whatever route he/she needs to reach a certain host in the server's LAN, so just not pushing certain route is not going to help you achieve that.

**Update:**

To enable IP forwarding (and make the setting persistent over boots):

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

To allow only forwarding that you need in this case (`eth0` and `tun0` are assumed):

```
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -i tun0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -d 192.168.1.20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

To do source NAT for forwarding traffics (so that you don't have to configure return route on `NAS` / `ROUTER`) that goes out via `eth0`:

```
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
```

(skip the above if you have some other rules in the chain that you also need)

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**or**, if the IP of `eth0` is persistent over time/boots:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT 192.168.1.88
```

P.S. If you want to flush the tables you touched, you can do:

```
for i in $(cat /proc/net/ip_tables_names); do iptables-restore /usr/share/iptables/empty-"$i".rules; done
```

Also note that `iptables` commands are not persistent over boots, so you will want to save the rules to a file with `iptables-save` (and configure your system to restore them on boot by some means).

**Update 2**:

You should really check out the above for how to properly configure the `FORWARD` chain (in the `filter` table). Without the `DROP` policy (or a "default" `DROP` rule at the end), any `ACCEPT` rule would be useless. (And your rule wouldn't be enough once you fix the `DROP` part)

To avoid subnet (more precisely, route) conflict, it's best to push a host route (it's what you need anyway) instead of a subnet route, so you should `push "route 192.168.1.20 255.255.255.255"` (the subnet mask can actually be omitted) instead, as the chance that a client host would have a host route to a LAN host (other than the default gateway) is much lower (a subnet route is always added on Linux when a non-`/32` address is assigned to an interface).

You can also for example `push "route 10.8.1.1"` and `DNAT` the destination to `192.168.1.20` on `Rasp.Pi` for the corner case where a `192.168.1.20` route already exists on a client (you should then still be able to access `NAS` with `10.8.1.1`):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.8.1.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.20
```

Comment: I'm not clear how I could do that. Should I add a line in server configuration? Or in client configuration? Or set a routing rule through a shell command? Believe me, I am trying hard and still reading a lot about routing, but I am still very confused about how I set up routing rules.

Comment: Neither, but the configuration of `NAS` or `Router`. How exactly you add a route to either of them (and whether that's possible) highly depends on the devices themselves (their OSes, their administration interfaces, etc.). When I have time I will update my answer with the iptables rules I mentioned that can be used on `Rasp.Pi` as alternatives to return route.

Comment: Today I tried in the Rasp.Pi the rule `iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.20 -j ACCEPT` but it didn't work. I have no idea how something similar could work in the NAS itself, since it is the "unreached" ending point so far. Sorry for my poor understanding of the matter.

Comment: What you need to add to `NAS` or `ROUTER` is a route. If you don't know how, just check out my updated answer for doing source NAT on `Rasp.Pi`. For the record, you don't *have to* mess with the `FORWARD` chain (in the `filter` table) to make it work. `filter` table is where you guard your LAN from your VPN (and so on), so essentially, it's optional. (What's mandatory is enabling IP forwarding with `sysctl`.)

Comment: I had my system working and complete yesterday, just before reading your second update. I had implemented the same setting: moving the "push route" command to specific IP worked like a charm to resolve any subnet route conflict (except the same-IP conflict, which I don't mind). So, changing to `push "route 192.168.1.20 255.255.255.255"` was the final step. Thank you for your precious help.